# wordpress admin part is not accesbile after server shifting

Tags: php, fatal-error, paths

one of my site's wp-admin is not accesible but the site front part is loading. This happens after i accessed the site from my new server second time. at first nothing happens and i can logg into dashboard. then after i logged out and second time try to login this error happens. when accessing the mysite.com/wp-admin the page shows

```
The page isn't redirecting properly.Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

in the public_html/error_log :

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 76
PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 76
```

cpanel error_log shows:

```
Permission denied: /home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

the htaccess have 644 permission. but i changed it into 775 and 755 and checked. the same happens.
what could be the reason? how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are following possibilities when you cann't open wp-admin
 1.There should be some file missing
 2.Some function deny to login in themes files
 3.Some plugin may also create issue

Solution:-
1.Replace all files from new WordPress except wp-content and wp-config file
 1. Rename your theme folder in wp-content
 2. Rename Plugins folder in wp-content

Hope this will work for you
thanks
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing.. a file which is required wordpress is missing so admin is not working properly to fix it just replace your wp-include folder with the exact version you have or there could be some permission issue just check all file has 775 as the permission

Comment: okay..let me check..and will  inform u..

Comment: no hope.. :( i've re-uploaded the copy and permission changed to 775. but still shows same.

Comment: check for folder permision

Comment: folder permission also changed to 775.. please find my updated post. i have added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try to get your website back live:

1. Try renewing the "**.htaccess**" file in your File Manager. 
   (**Note:** It is a hidden file.)

Here's the default code for the .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

2. Check the wp_options table in your phpMyAdmin and make sure the **site URL and home URL** are the same as your website. Also check if either one of these is on HTTP or HTTPS which may be the reason this isn't working.

If both these solutions doesn't work, you can contact me at [DimonsThoughts](https://dimonsthoughts.com) or here & I will help you.